# Firestore security rules: Function [get] called with malformed path

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, firebase-console

> **Cloud Firestore Rule**

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /admins/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }

    match /{userId}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId || get(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(userId)/users/$(request.auth.token.email)).exists;
    }
  }
}
```

> **Details provided in Rules Playground of Cloud Firestore**

**Simulation type**: get

**Location**: /databases/(default)/documents/cTgy9W6Zt2dShSgqig2ToeYLEzt2/products

**Authenticated**: True

##### Authentication Payload

```
{
  "uid": "dQkped8ggvUv6iHfI9kVD7Vrnlf2",
  "token": {
    "sub": "dQkped8ggvUv6iHfI9kVD7Vrnlf2",
    "aud": "undefined",
    "email": "abc@example.com",
    "email_verified": false,
    "firebase": {
      "sign_in_provider": "password"
    }
  }
}
```

> **Error**

```
Function [get] called with malformed path: /databases/(default)/documents/cTgy9W6Zt2dShSgqig2ToeYLEzt2/users/abc@example.com
```

[image: Please see this image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a Document path to the [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore?authuser=0#.get) method.

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions?authuser=0#access_other_documents): "The `get()` and `exists()` functions both expect fully specified document paths."

With

```
/databases/$(database)/documents/$(userId)/users/$(request.auth.token.email)
```

you are actually passing a Collection path (3 elements).

You need to change your data model or add a document in the `abc@example.com` subcollection to point to.

---

**In addition** I think you're mixing up the `get()` and `exists()` functions.

The `get()` method returns a [`rules.firestore.Resource`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource?authuser=0) which does not have an `exists` property.

So doing `get(**path**).exists` cannot work. You should either use `exists()` to check if a specific document exists or use `get()` to check the value of a field of the specific document through the [`data`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource?authuser=0#data) property.

Comment: I know it automatically add `/databases/(default)/documents` as the prefix and I pass `cTgy9W6Zt2dShSgqig2ToeYLEzt2/products` only to the `path/to/resource` field

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've totally modified my answer: the problem comes from the path you pass to the `get()` method in your security rule.

Comment: Thanks @Renaud Tarnec to tell we can pass 2 elements to Collection Path I fixed the problem by using `get(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(userId)/users).data[request.auth.token.email] != null` I have converted collection to a map field and it works